# How to seperate ' test(a =10)' and 'test' in python

Tags: python

I want to do this:

```
a = TestClass1() <br>
a.test.fun()   #==> this i want to call TestClass2 method fun() <br>
a.test(a=10).fun() #===> this i want to call TestClass3 method fun() <br>
```

Does anyone know how to separate this?

I have three classes:

```
class TestClass1:
    aa = ""
    def __init__(self):
        self.aa = "ccc"
    def __getattr__(self, item):
        print("test 1 get attr = ",item)
        return TestClass2()  or TestClass3()  #==> I don't how to seperate test and test(a =10)
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        print("__getitem__",item)

class TestClass2:
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("TestClass2  __call__ ")
        return self
    def fun(self):
        print("this TestClass2 fun()")

class TestClass3:
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("TestClass3  33333 call 3 ")
        return self
    def fun(self):
        print("this TestClass3 fun()")
```

Comment: Perhaps meaningful identifiers would help to better understand the problem. As it is I can't find the idea of having unrelated classes disguising as the other attractive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in both examples given `__getattr__` is called with argument `"test"`.
you need to do something like this:

```
class TestClass1:
    def __getattr__(self, item):
        if item == 'test2':
            return TestClass2()
        elif item == 'test3':
            return TestClass3()

a = TestClass1()
a.test2.fun()
a.test3.fun()
```

**EDIT:** Let me explain further. Well, in python there is no difference between a function and an attribute, everything in python is an object, all objects are treated the same, be it an integer or a function.
When you do `a.test` it is lowered to `a.__getattr__('test')`.
And when you do `a.test(a=10)` it is lowered to `a.__getattr__('test')(a=10)`.
The returned object from `a.__getattr__('test')` is the same.
In the second case you are fetching the attribute `test` **then** calling it with an argument `a=10`.
**EDIT2:** What you are trying to do could be achieved this way:

```
class TestClass1:
    test = TestClass2()

class TestClass2:
    def __call__(self, a):
        if a == 10:
            return TestClass3()

    def fun():
        print("this TestClass2 fun()")

a = TestClass1()
a.test           # this is TestClass2
a.test.fun       # this is TestClass2.fun
a.test(a=10)     # this is TestClass3
a.test(a=10).fun # this is TestClass3.fun
```

**EDIT3:** A simpler approach would be making `test` a function:

```
class TestClass1:
    def test(a=None):
        if a is None:
            return TestClass2()
        if a == 10:
            return TestClass3()

a = TestClass1()
a.test().fun      # TestClass2.fun
a.test(a=10).fun  # TestClass3.fun
```

Comment: Thank you for response, It is OK,but when the  name  is the same ,i don't know how to seperate attribute 'test' and the function call like 'test(a =10)'

Comment: I added a little bit of explanation. let me know if I need to explain further.

Comment: I added an example of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for your patience to answer.
I want to do this ,bucause i want the 'test' and 'test(a =10)' return a c++ instance,this instance have a lot of method,
like the 'fun()',and i don't want to list all of them in my python code ,so i want to call them direct.
the different between 'test' and 'test(a =10)' is that the 'test(a =10)' must set some parameter before call c++ instance method like fun(),
so i want to seperate then before call then fun();

Comment: I see, then maybe make `test` a function, see EDIT3 above. That is what they call a _factory function_.

Comment: Thank you very much  ,the EDIT2 is good idea ! This is i want! thank you for  give a good answer!